# Pl sql How to save 2 output value in another procedure in 2 distinct variable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Hy Guys,

unfortunately i'm just starting with plsql, and i have this little problem.
What I would like to do is save the two outputs in 2 different variables. Is possible?

I write my code.

```
PROCEDURE TEST1 (SEQ NUMBER, QUERY_STR OUT VARCHAR2, NAME_PROCEDURE OUT VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
 QUERY_STR:='select * from name where seq='|| SEQ;
 NAME_PROCEDURE:='test1'
END TEST1;


PROCEDURE MAIN (SEQ NUMBER) AS
-- var1:= TEST1(SEQ); -- save here the QUERY_STR
-- var2:= TEST(SEQ)-- save here the NAME_PROCEDURE
END MAIN;
```

thx all for the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create or replace procedure test1
  2    (seq number, query_str out varchar2, name_procedure out varchar2)
  3  as
  4  begin
  5   query_str := 'select * from dept where deptno = ' || seq;
  6   name_procedure := 'test1';
  7  end test1;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace procedure main (seq number) as
  2    var1 varchar2(200);
  3    var2 varchar2(200);
  4  begin
  5    test1(seq, var1, var2);
  6    dbms_output.put_line('var1 = ' || var1);
  7    dbms_output.put_line('var2 = ' || var2);
  8  end main;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    main (seq => 10);
  3  end;
  4  /
var1 = select * from dept where deptno = 10
var2 = test1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Littlefoot, Monday morning, when I'm back to home I test it, check you so much.